# Find that the subspace $M$ is precompact in the space of all convergent sequences $c$

Tags: functional-analysis

Recently, I found this problem in the notes of my functional analysis course and tried to solve it with the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem which states that a subset is precompact if it is bounded and it is equicontinous, or with the Riesz theorem.

> Find that the subspace $M$ is precompact in the space $c$, where M is bounded and $\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n > N, \forall x=(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)\in M$ we have that $|x_{n}-\lim x_{n}|<\epsilon$.

For the first part, we can see that we already have that $M$ is bounded, and the rest of the properties given, shout at me to try to solve with equicontinuity, but I don't know if that is possible in the space of sequences, or if this concept is reserved only for function spaces.

The definition of equicontinuity that was given to us in the course is the following:

> $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y$ we have $|x-y|<\delta$ then it holds that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Also, if this is not the way to do it, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry it is $x_n$

Comment: Which direction of the iff are you failing to prove? Is it "only"  (for every bounded $M\subset c$): $M$ precompact $\implies\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\dots?$ (this is what your body says, but your title says $\impliedby$)

Comment: Please edit your post to replace "subspace" by "subset" and to spell correctly the name of the mathematicians. Also, I think the notation $x_{n}-\lim x$ would be cleaner than $x_{n}-\lim x_n$ (the notation 
 $\color{red}{x=}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)$ seems to have been introduced for this purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c$ "is" the space of continuous functions from $\Bbb N^+$ to $\Bbb R,$ where $\Bbb N^+=\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ is the [one point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification) of the discrete space $\Bbb N.$ The point $\infty$ is the only non-isolated point of $\Bbb N^+,$ and the [general definition of equicontinuity at some point of a topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_between_metric_spaces), when applied to  $M$ at this point of $\Bbb N^+,$ rewrites precisely $$\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists N,\forall n > N, \forall x=(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)\in M,|x_{n}-\lim x|<\epsilon.$$

Note also that if $M\subset c$ is bounded then for every $x\in\Bbb N^+,$ $M(x)\subset\Bbb R$ is bounded.

Therefore, the implication you want to prove is nothing else than the corresponding implication in the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces) applied to that space $c=C(\Bbb N^+,\Bbb R).$

Same for the converse implications, after checking the following: if $M$ is equicontinuous at $\infty$ and if $M(x)\subset\Bbb R$ is bounded for every $x\in\Bbb N^+,$ then $M\subset c$ is bounded.