# Prove that $M$ is precompact in $c$ (The space of all convergent sequences)

Tags: functional-analysis

First I would like to comment that I found this problem in my book of functional analysis:

Prove that the subspace $M$ is precompact in the space $c$, where M is bounded and $\forall\epsilon > 0, \exists N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n > N, \forall x=(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)\in M$ we have that $|x_{n}-\lim x_{n}|<\epsilon$.

Doing some research I found that someone asked this question in this site before: [Find that the subspace $M$ is precompact in the space of all convergent sequences $c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790203/find-that-the-subspace-m-is-precompact-in-the-space-of-all-convergent-sequence).
But, first the logic this person gives is wrong, as you can not use the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem in this case, and also equicontinuity is for a function space not a sequence space.
Regarding this, I read the answer that is given, and I am not convinced it is exactly the answer for this problem, as the person who answers changes the definition of the space at hand.

To further clarify this, the problem works with the space $c$,which is the space of all convergent sequences $(x_{n})$ of real or complex numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_space). With this I tried to solve the problem by using the Hausdorff criteria which I saw it in class in this way:

> Let $(X,\rho)$ be a complete metric space, then $N\subset X$ is precompact if and only if it is totally bounded.

So my idea was to prove that the subset $M$ is totally bounded by constructing a $\epsilon$-net (As the definition of a totally bounded set is a set that has the existence of a finite $\epsilon$-net), which is defined by:

> Let $N\subset(X,\rho),Y\subset X$ then $Y$ is an $\epsilon$-net for $X$ if $\forall x\in X$ there exists a $y\in Y$ such that we have that $\bigcup B(y,\epsilon)\subset X$ (open balls) and radius $r(x,y)<\epsilon$.

So I tried to construct this thing, but to be honest I couldn't, I feel this is really simple but I am stuck. If anyone can help I would be gratefull.

Comment: The space $c$ is isometrically isomorphic to the space $C(K),$ where $K=\{0\}\cup \{n^{-1}\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset \mathbb{R}$, so applying the Arzeli-Ascoli theorem is justified.

Comment: Oh, I didnt knew that, but if I want to find the $\epsilon$-net how should I do it ?

Comment: The space $c$ of convergent sequences **is** the space of all continuous functions $C(\mathbb N^*)$ where $\mathbb N^*=\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ is a compact metric space with the metric $d(n,m)=|1/n-1/m|$ (with $1/\infty=0$).

Comment: @Jochen Why is $c$ that space, I cant see it.

Comment: An isometric isomorphism $C(\mathbb N^*)\to c$ is given by $f\mapsto f|_{\mathbb N}$ -- note that a sequence is nothing but a function on $\mathbb N$.